# Rate of Thermal Conduction between different materials

Tags: thermal-conduction

I'm aiming to use differential equations to simulate thermal transfer between different materials in a 3D space, however, my physics knowledge is lacking.  Is there a formula that can give the rate of thermal transfer between two different materials (e.g copper, aluminium) with a two-dimensional area of contact?

Comment: Have you read [thermal contact conductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_contact_conductance)? [Fourier's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction#Fourier's_law) and conservation of energy.

Comment: You have two bodies made of two different  materials that are put into contact at time zero and allowed to thermally equilibrate over time.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a formula known as Fourier's Law, which essentially states that

$Q = -k \cdot A \cdot \frac{dT}{dx}$

Where:

- Q is the rate of heat transfer (in watts, W).
- k is the thermal conductivity of the material (in watts per meter-kelvin, W/(m·K)).
- A is the cross-sectional area through which heat is transferring (in square meters, m^2).
- (dT/dx) is the temperature gradient across the material (in kelvin per meter, K/m).

This formula applies to one-dimensional heat conduction, but you can adapt it to 3D by considering the heat flow in each spatial direction (x, y, and z) separately.

For your specific case with two different materials (e.g., copper and aluminum) in contact, you would need to consider the interface between them. The rate of heat transfer will depend on the thermal conductivity of both materials and the temperature difference across the interface.

To calculate the rate of heat transfer for a 2D area of contact, you'll need to determine the temperature gradient (dT/dx) along the interface and multiply it by the effective cross-sectional area (A) through which heat is transferring. This area will depend on the shape and dimensions of the contact region.

Keep in mind that if you're working with a complex 3D space and need to account for heat transfer in multiple directions, you'll need to apply Fourier's Law separately for each direction and consider boundary conditions. Numerical methods, such as finite element analysis or finite difference methods, are often used to solve these types of problems when dealing with 3D spaces and complex geometries. These methods involve discretizing the space into small elements and solving differential equations numerically to simulate heat transfer accurately.

Comment: Thank you, that's extremely helpful.